# Convert all strings to interpolated strings

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, resharper, automated-refactoring

I'd like to replace all string literals in my project with interpolated strings. I didn't find any option for this in the R# / Code cleanUp / ReFactor settings. I don't care if it's another solution (e.g. containing the search and replace option of VS with RegEx).

An example:

```cs
Console.WriteLine ("foo{myVariable}"); Console.WriteLine (Console.ReadLine() == "fee{myVariable}" || Console.ReadLine() == $"fii{myVariable}");
```

should be converted to:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"foo{myVariable}"); Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine() == $"fee{myVariable}" || Console.ReadLine() == $"fii{myVariable}");
```

I already gave it a try with RegEx but failed. This was my search string:

```regex
^(?<toKeep>[^"\n]+.[^$"])(?<toReplace>")
```

And this my replacement string:

```regex
${toKeep}$"
```

The problem here is, that it matches only the first string of a line and also matches strings in my XML documentation.

Another problem, which occurred, is, that not all strings can be safely converted to interpolated strings - switch cases for example require constant types as arguments. This problem, however, can be ignored, as it isn't too difficult to remove the interpolation signs here.

Comment: `"foo{myVariable}"` and `"$foo{myVariable}"` produce completely different output.  I doubt you will find an extension that converts the former to the latter, since most such extensions would be designed not to change behavior.

Comment: @BJMyers But this is exactly what I need. As I said, it doesn't have to be solved with an extension. A method with RegEx would be fine for me as well.

Comment: Curious - why do you have a bunch of strings in that format anyway?  That seems profoundly unhelpful.

Comment: @BJMyers I have them, because I replaced a string with a string located somewhere else and did this with find & replace, not thinking of the possibility of normal strings existing in my project. But even if this wasn't the case, my strings would still contain stuff like curled brackets.

Comment: @BJMyers Would it be any different, if there wasn't stuff like this? This would be helpfull as well, because it shouldn't be too difficult to replace those brackets with escaped brackets and later replace the escaped ones with curled brackets again.

Comment: I tried to gain insight into your abstract question. Looked at the regex, didn't help. Are you just trying to match quoted strings outside of comments ?

Comment: Hope you are working with c# version 6.0 and above to get this feature working properly.

Comment: @user3499361 yes I am.

Comment: @sln in my RegEx I just tried to match all first quotes of a string identifier (look at the examples). Because you obviously can't just replace all " with $", because the dollar sign would be written inside the string as well then.

Comment: What do expect `Console.ReadLine() == "fee{myVariable}" || Console.ReadLine() == $"fii{myVariable}"` to do? When do you expect it read one line and when do you expect it to read two lines?

Comment: @AdrianHHH It was just an example. And yeah, I know that it would sometimes read two lines (if the first expression was false).

Comment: You have to use the rule's that are in place to parse quoted literals `".."` of the language source that you are parsing. It's not good enough to use something like `^.*?"` or that's how lang's would parse it.